# angular bootstrap tabs - select function called in page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I have the angular bootstrap tabs in the following format. (see the plunker)

The select function is supposed to trigger when the tabs are selected. But strangely, when the page is loaded, the very first tab's select function gets triggered. (prints tab selected Dynamic Title 1 onload..)

```
"http://plnkr.co/edit/vyOOhCdIl7s1Wvou7Dr9?p=preview"
```

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 3', content:'Dynamic content 3' }
  ];
  
  $scope.tabSelect = function(title){
    console.log("tab selected "+title);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
      <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled" select="tabSelect(tab.title)">
          {{tab.content}}
        </tab>
      </tabset>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [`select() (Defaults: null) : An optional expression called when tab is activated`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) so it makes sense, during load by default first tab is activated and it fires the event.

Comment: is there nay way that we can avoid this in page load?

Comment: Looking through the source code of angular-ui there seems to be no way to specify that. However you can easily do 
  `var firstTime = true;
  $scope.tabSelect = function(title){
    if(firstTime){
       firstTime = false;
       return;
    }
    console.log("tab selected "+title);
  };`

Comment: `ng-click` solution works perfectly. Please consider accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your select to ng-click like this:

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" ng-click="tabSelect(tab.title)">
```